# Is there a French translation of the Brahma Sutra Bhasya of Shankara?

Tags: vedanta, translation-request, brahma-sutras

There are several English translations of the [Brahma Sutra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma_Sutras) Bhasya of Shankara, by Swamis speaking English.  I've never found a (complete) French translation.

**Question**: Is there a French translation of the Brahma Sutra Bhasya of Shankara?

**Remark**: Perhaps there is such a translation by a Swami native close to Pondicherry.

Comment: [related meta discussion](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/130/are-book-recommendations-on-topic/180#180)

Answer (score 7):

I found the book ["Le Vedanta : etude sur les Brahma-sutras et leurs cinq commentaires"](http://www.worldcat.org/title/le-vedanta-etude-sur-les-brahma-sutras-et-leurs-cinq-commentaires/oclc/301280005), which is a book with five commenatries on the Brahma Sutras, but I'm not sure whether it includes Adi Shankaracharya's commentary or not.  You may also be interested [this French translation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8186569022) of the Brahma Sutra itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, your first reference is a thesis dissertation of 146 pages, and so it can't contain a complete translation (because an English translation has 900 pages). About your second reference, there is a mistake, it's in Spanish, not in French (see the back cover).

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux Could it be that they just put the wrong cover photo?

Comment: In fact, I'm really looking for such a French translation and unfortunately this book is definitively in Spanish: see [this comment](http://www.amazon.fr/product-reviews/8186569022/ref=dp_db_cm_cr_acr_txt?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=1).

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux Apparently Olivier Lacombe wrote a translation of Ramanujacharya's commentary on the Brahma Sutras in 1938: https://books.google.com/books?id=JkOAEdIsdUsC&lpg=PA157&ots=SN5jpTNUzp&dq=brahma%20sutra%20french&pg=PA157#v=onepage&q&f=false (Ramanujacharya was a topic of some fascination in Europe at some point because people mistakenly believed he drew inspiration from Jesus and Christianity.)  I'm not sure if it's out of print though.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux It's available in a library in Paris: http://www.worldcat.org/title/doctrine-morale-et-metaphysique-de-ramanuja/oclc/493399445/editions?referer=di&editionsView=true And you can also buy it: http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?isbn=&an=olivier%20lacombe&tn=la%20doctrine%20morale%20et%20metaphysique%20de%20ramanuja&n=100121503